# Authentication with Ocelot and Microservices

Tags: c#, .net, security, authentication, ocelot

I have created an authentication server that returns an access token. With this access token you can access the api gateway and a dashboard microservice. The API gateway was created in C# with Ocelot. When I make a call to the API gateway it is correctly redirected to the dashboard microservice. I've created a secure route in the dashboard microservice and also send a JWT token to it, yet the application says I'm unauthorized? What misconfiguration have I made here?

API Gateway Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var audienceConfig = Configuration.GetSection("Audience");
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(audienceConfig["Secret"]));
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = audienceConfig["Iss"],
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = audienceConfig["Aud"],
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            });
            services.AddOcelot();
        }
```

Ocelot Configuration:

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/dashboard/all",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 44391
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/dashboard",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ],
      "AuthenticationOptions": {
        "AuthenticationProviderKey": "Bearer",
        "AllowedScopes": []
      }
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5021"
  }
}
```

Dashboard Microservice Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "DashboardMicroservice", Version = "v1" });
            });
            services.AddControllers();


            var audienceConfig = Configuration.GetSection("Audience");
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(audienceConfig["Secret"]));
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = audienceConfig["Iss"],
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = audienceConfig["Aud"],
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
            };

            services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
            });
        }
```

Appsettings DashboardMicroservice:

```
{
  "Audience": {
    "Secret": "7B264QtbEafewaL4zIlLed9Zlun31jGXWduRhF1YChXDl_JPlz6k5ZILTU525y8D1HMAo79CytI",
    "Iss": "https://localhost:5001",
    "Aud": "https://localhost:5001"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

The request I am making:
[image]

And the output:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In controller you need to specify the AuthenticationSchemes.

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes="Bearer")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "Catcher Wong", "James Li" };
    }
```